Exclude CSS while extracting link with LinkExtactor Scrapy
I been working on a 3 level depth crawl where I need to exclude some CSS classes like the header and the footer,I tried using the attribute "restrict_css" with the :not("#header") but it's not working and
I'm not really sure what's the best way to extract all links using the LinkExtractor
I tried:
LinkExtractor(restrict_css=":not(#header)")

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In Scrapy, the restrict_css parameter in LinkExtractor is used to specify which parts of the page to scan for links, not which parts to exclude directly.
However, you can effectively exclude certain areas by 2 methods:
1. By being more specific about where you want to include links from.
Instead of trying to exclude the header using :not(#header), it would be more straightforward to directly include the areas you want.
Use multiple selectors separated by commas if necessary.
Here’s an example, assuming .main-content and .sidebar are the areas you want to include:
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

link_extractor = LinkExtractor(restrict_css=('.main-content', '.sidebar'))

2. By using the deny parameter to specific about where you want to exclude links from.
If you still want to try and exclude the header and footer while being less specific about the inclusion areas, you could try using the deny parameter with XPath expressions that match the header and footer.
link_extractor = LinkExtractor(deny=(r'//*[@id="header"]', r'//*[@id="footer"]'))

In this example, the deny parameter is used to exclude any links found within the elements with id="header" and id="footer" using XPath.
Make sure to adjust the selectors according to the actual structure and styles of your target website.

Thanks for your response, the second option it's the way to go for me but I'm receiving an error while trying to use it, seems like deny it's only a rule that apply to the URLS not to the tags
